# Сделать Universal Image Loader что бы он работал не с Активити, а с Фрагментами

Tags: android, java

Хочу сделать Universal Image Loader что бы он работал не с Активити, а с Фрагментами...

т.к. я новичок в этом не легком деле прошу помощи у вас знатоков...

есть Активити, в ней через Лайаут стоит Фрагмент на другую активити!
вот и хотелось бы сделать в этом фрагменте Universal Image Loader...

вот код:

```
package com.chhavi.universalimageloader;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;

/**
 * Created by vivek on 6/25/13.
 */
public class ListOfImages extends Activity {
     protected AbsListView list;
     protected ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    final Context context=this;
    DisplayImageOptions op;

    //String[] imageUrls={"R.drawable.one","R.drawable.two","R.drawable.three"};
     String [] images={"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZrajzoEXNlRWjMGE9L3kqI1EsFN9P5HCNhMo4xaqLkWuhAixo","http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQH7hisM_szjOKlVdQvq6m_J4lETkWxQOlAk3SMWs051TFFnmWMCA","http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png"};  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_listview_layout);

        op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
//                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
                .build();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ((ListView) list).setAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //tartImagePagerActivity(position);

                Intent i=new Intent(context,SeperateView.class);
                i.putExtra("pos",position+"");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

//    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
//        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
//        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
//        startActivity(intent);
//    }

    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        //private ImageLoadingListener animate = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;
            public ImageView image;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_list_layout, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));

            loader.displayImage(images[position], holder.image, op, null);

            return v;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: @sviter-pro, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: "стоит Фрагмент на другую активити" - судя по этому выражению, у активити эрекция на другую активити    
простите, не удержался    
Выложите код вашего фрагмента, в котором вы хотите использовать UniversalImageLoader    
А то вообще ни чего не понятно, что вы хотите...

Comment: public class ListOfImages extends Activity { а мне надо ListFragment, но там идут ошибки если я просто заменяю Активити на ЛистФрагмент. Можно это как нибудь исправить или по новой все переписывать придется?

Comment: для начала придется прочитать, что такое фрагменты, и как с ними работать.

Comment: это то может и понятно!но код ругается сильно....